# Leaflet ImageOverlay Image does not appear

Tags: leaflet, django

I'm trying to stitch the picture taken from my drone onto the map, and I'm using Django 1.11.14 and latest version leaflet 1.3.4. I tried to use [ImageOverlay](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#imageoverlay), there is no error but the image does not appear on my map

```
var imageUrl = "/media/photos/2018/10/18/DJI_0001_2.JPG";
var imageBounds = [[101.6999678,2.9244267], [101.611, 2.983226]];
L.imageOverlay(imageUrl, imageBounds).addTo(map);
map.fitBounds(imageBounds);
```

Comment: Not so experienced with js, but the example you link to uses the syntax: `var imageUrl = "/media/photos/2018/10/18/DJI_0001_2.JPG",
imageBounds = [[101.6999678,2.9244267], [101.611, 2.983226]];`. I.e. replace `;` with `'` after '...2.JPG"' and loose the second `var`. I doubt this is the only issue though.

Comment: @RoperMaps Both approaches are completely valid.

Comment: @OP The console is completely empty? You could bind a listener to the `imageOverlay`: `on('error', function (e) { console.log(e) })`

Comment: @Stefan_Fairphone thank you Stefan for the respond, apparently I mismatched the latlong. It works well now, however the image is not properly stitch as it appear bigger than it supposed to be. my appologies I'm really new to this

Comment: Please update your question accordingly or answer this one and create a new question.